# How filter Not NULL rows after multiple LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I want to JOIN a base table with another 23 tables. But as I want to join one with another tables, I have to use LEFT JOIN. My query sample:

```
SELECT notif_dest_user.notif_id,
       notif_all.da,
       COALESCE(notif_trick_like.uft_id, notif_trick_comment.uft_id) AS uft_id,
       COALESCE(like_users.un, trickComment_users.un)                AS un,
       COALESCE(like_tricks.tr_n, trickComment_tricks.tr_n)          AS tr_n,
       trickComment_userForTricks.cm_tx,
       COALESCE(trickComment_users.av_ul,like_users.av_ul)                       AS av_ul
FROM notif_dest_user
       LEFT JOIN notif_all ON notif_all.notif_id = notif_dest_user.notif_id
       LEFT JOIN notif_trick_like ON notif_dest_user.notif_id = notif_trick_like.notif_id
       LEFT JOIN user_for_tricks like_userForTricks ON notif_trick_like.uft_id = like_userForTricks.uft_id
       LEFT JOIN tricks like_tricks ON like_userForTricks.tr_id = like_tricks.tr_id
       LEFT JOIN users like_users ON like_userForTricks.u_id = like_users.u_id
       LEFT JOIN notif_trick_comment ON notif_trick_comment.notif_id = notif_dest_user.notif_id
       LEFT JOIN user_for_tricks trickComment_userForTricks
         on trickComment_userForTricks.uft_id = notif_trick_comment.uft_id
       LEFT JOIN users trickComment_users ON trickComment_users.u_id = trickComment_userForTricks.u_id
       LEFT JOIN tricks trickComment_tricks ON trickComment_tricks.tr_id = trickComment_userForTricks.tr_id
where notif_dest_user.dest_u_id = 42
limit 10;
```

The result of that query is like this:

```
+----------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
| notif_id | da         | uft_id  | un          | tr_n        | cm_tx       | av_ul                              |
+----------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
|       10 | 1542866579 | 1799477 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL                               |
|       11 | 1542866579 | 1799494 | Some result | Some result | Some result | pics/avatars/u2764_1504729707_3092 |
|       12 | 1542866579 | 1799386 | Some result | Some result | Some result |                                    |
|       13 | 1542866579 | 1799477 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL                               |
|       14 | 1542866579 | 1799494 | Some result | Some result | Some result | pics/avatars/u2764_1504729707_3092 |
|       15 | 1542866579 | 1799386 | Some result | Some result | Some result |                                    |
|       16 | 1542866579 | 1799477 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL                               |
|       17 | 1542866579 | 1799494 | Some result | Some result | Some result | pics/avatars/u2764_1504729707_3092 |
|       18 | 1542866579 | 1799386 | Some result | Some result | Some result |                                    |
|       19 | 1542866579 | 1799477 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL                               |
+----------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------------+
```

But I don't want to get the rows that were not exist (NULL) in right-side tables (other 23 tables). In other words, I want to show sum of rows of separately INNER JOIN between the base table and other tables. Something like this:

```
+----------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| notif_id | da         | uft_id  | un          | tr_n        | cm_tx       | av_ul                               |
+----------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
|    10000 | 1542866579 | 1799408 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
|    10001 | 1542866579 | 1799554 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u87332_1521754761_3673 |
|    10002 | 1542866579 | 1799422 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
|    10003 | 1542866579 | 1799408 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
|    10004 | 1542866579 | 1799554 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u87332_1521754761_3673 |
|    10005 | 1542866579 | 1799422 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
|    10006 | 1542866579 | 1799408 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
|    10007 | 1542866579 | 1799554 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u87332_1521754761_3673 |
|    10008 | 1542866579 | 1799422 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
|    10009 | 1542866579 | 1799408 | some result | some result | some result | pics/avatars/u63067_1517939524_6583 |
+----------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `trickComment_userForTricks.cm_tx` field in output list is a single-selected (coalesce is not used), so use this field as a mark. To remove NULL-contained records replace `LEFT JOIN user_for_tricks trickComment_userForTricks` with `INER JOIN`.

Comment: This cause remove all rows in left-side columns that doesn't have same id in user_for_tricks trickComment_userForTricks !!

Comment: *This cause remove all rows in left-side columns that doesn't have same id in user_for_tricks trickComment_userForTricks* ... and all those rows will have `cm_tx IS NULL`... and you want to remove them from your output... I do not see the contradiction.

Comment: No. I want to remove rows exists in left-side base table, but not exists at least in one of right-side tables. It's a few different than what you say

Comment: *I want to remove rows exists in left-side base table, but not exists at least in one of right-side tables.* If so you must use INNER join for all joins... but this task differs from initial task. *It's a few different than what you say* It's a few different than what you say in a question text. But it is your task, and you can do everything you want with it, it is. In any case - you use LEFT JOIN to add NULLs, and then you want to remove this NULLs added by LEFT JOIN... it's strange.

Comment: OK. I understood what you're saying. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1) If you want to filter out rows that have no match in the right table, skip the `LEFT` keyword and use the regular (inner) join.

2) If you want to filter out rows that have all expressions evaluated to NULL, use regular WHERE clause, like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE COALESCE(notif_trick_like.uft_id, notif_trick_comment.uft_id) IS NOT NULL
OR COALESCE(like_users.un, trickComment_users.un) IS NOT NULL
OR COALESCE(like_tricks.tr_n, trickComment_tricks.tr_n) IS NOT NULL
OR trickComment_userForTricks.cm_tx IS NOT NULL
OR COALESCE(trickComment_users.av_ul,like_users.av_ul) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The second option can be used. But isn't there another option that don't need pass conditions in 'WHERE' and 'IS NOT NULL' ? I think this way is some risky. Because right-side tables might have NULL values inside.

Comment: Right-side table has at least one not-null field (the ID). You can filter on it. 

Actually it depends on what you want. It's not 100% clear from the question.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. But the another problem is query response time. When I add this where clause, I take longer (about 2x) time to execute query.

Comment: @DoctorHenry do you have indexes on the join fields? It can help in some cases. If you need help on query tuning, post the query plan here. EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON should be ok

Comment: My tables' indices were defined well. you can see here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/a3xni

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to avoid the `NOT NULL` rows, this is the pattern:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON ...
    WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

This extends to multiple `LEFT JOINs` and multiple tests `AND'd` together in the `WHERE`.

As already mentioned, avoiding the `NULL` rows, change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

(A side note:  The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional and ignored by MySQL.)